# PHP Laravel API, The requested URL not found using MAMP

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

This is my first Laravel api app. Database, Models, Controllers all are connected but when i tried to call api endpoints as you seen in the screenshot below, it gives a error 
**"The requested URL /zidd/api/posts was not found on this server"** 
when i call **zidd/public** it shows Laravel homepage. (Zidd is my project name)

i have tried to add .htaccess (RewriteEngine On) and http.conf (AllowOverride All) as well but still the problem is same.

i am using MAMP on MacOS.

[image: route:list]

Comment: On your command line try running this command `php artisan serve` and see what it comes out with. This creates a virtual server pre-configured to run Laravel apps.

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign it shows http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Awesome! Now you can just visit that url and everything will work just fine.Just make sure to keep that terminal window running as long as you're working. Once you stop that command from running then that URL will no longer work.

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign i tried "http://127.0.0.1:8000/zidd/api/posts" still the same problem :(

Comment: you don't need to add `/zidd`. just visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/`

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign Its working yippe :) Thanks and I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: No problem. Just so happened to be browsing around. Hey also I would suggest you taking a look at Laravel\Valet (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet). It pretty much replaces the need for MAMP and works flawlessly with Laravel as it should lol.